# Add a mapping to an existing index template (using NEST attributes)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

In my ElasticSearch server, I have an *existing* index template, which contains some settings and some mappings.

I want to add a mapping for a new type to the template, but since it's not possible to update templates, I need to delete the existing one and recreate it.

Since I would like to keep all the existing settings, I tried getting the existing definition, add the mapping to it and then delete/recreate, like in this example:

```
using Nest;
using System;

public class SomeNewType {
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string SomeField { get; set; }
    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed)]
    public string AnotherField { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri: new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"));
        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
        var templateResponse = client.GetTemplate("sometemplate");
        var template = templateResponse.TemplateMapping;
        client.DeleteTemplate("sometemplate");
        // Add a mapping to the template somehow...
        template.Mappings.Add( ... );
        var putTemplateRequest = new PutTemplateRequest("sometemplate") {
            TemplateMapping = template
        };
        client.PutTemplate(putTemplateRequest);
    }
}
```

However, I cannot find a way to add a mapping to the template definition using the ElasticProperty attributes, like in

```
client.Map<SomeNewType>(m => m.MapFromAttributes());
```

Is it possible to create a `RootObjectMapping` to add to the `Mappings` collection with something similar to `MapFromAttributes`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using the more robust `PutMappingDescriptor` to get a new `RootObjectMapping`, then add that into the collection returned by your `GET _template` request, like so:

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(uri: new Uri("http://localhost:9200/"));
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var templateResponse = client.GetTemplate("sometemplate");
var template = templateResponse.TemplateMapping;
// Don't delete, this way other settings will stay intact and the PUT will override ONLY the mappings.
// client.DeleteTemplate("sometemplate");

// Add a mapping to the template like this...
PutMappingDescriptor<SomeNewType> mapper = new PutMappingDescriptor<SomeNewType>(settings);
mapper.MapFromAttributes();
RootObjectMapping newmap = ((IPutMappingRequest) mapper).Mapping;

TypeNameResolver r = new TypeNameResolver(settings);
string mappingName = r.GetTypeNameFor(typeof(SomeNewType));

template.Mappings.Add(mappingName, newmap);

var putTemplateRequest = new PutTemplateRequest("sometemplate")
{
    TemplateMapping = template
};

var result = client.PutTemplate(putTemplateRequest);
```

Note: TypeNameResolver is in the `Nest.Resolvers` namespace

As noted in the comment above, I recommend that you NOT delete the old template if the mappings are the only thing that needs updated, otherwise you will need to copy all of the other relevant settings into your new request.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. About the delete, it looks like the settings are kept even if I delete the template: after all, the `GET _template` request is returning the settings as well, right?